# Transient clicking sound in Android AudioRecorder

Tags: android, android-audiorecord

I'm a beginner in Android programming!

My hardware is a Samsung Galaxy Young GT-S5360!

With my app I want to record something using the mic source.

If I record a sine with 1000Hz or other sound samples I always get two transients or clicking sounds at the beginning of the sample. After 0,200s the sample looks ok for me.

How can I elimenate these transients?!

Here's my code which I'm using found on the web:

```
private void startrec(){
  File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"test.pcm" ); 

  int minBufferSize = audioRecord.getMinBufferSize(44100, 
             AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO, 
             AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT);

  short[] audioData = new short[minBufferSize];

  try {
   file.createNewFile();

   OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);

   BufferedOutputStream bufferedOutputStream = new BufferedOutputStream(outputStream);

   DataOutputStream dataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(bufferedOutputStream);

   AudioRecord audioRecord = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC,
     44100,
     AudioFormat.CHANNEL_CONFIGURATION_MONO,
     AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT,
     minBufferSize);

   audioRecord.startRecording();

   while(isRecording){
    int numberOfShort = audioRecord.read(audioData, 0, minBufferSize);

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfShort; i++){
     dataOutputStream.writeShort(audioData[i]);
    }
   }

   audioRecord.stop();
   audioRecord.release();
   dataOutputStream.close();

  } catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }
```

The `startrec()` function is called with a button click and is stopped with another button.
Maybe the Button-Click-Sound causes the transients at the beginning, because it also uses the same SOURCE(MIC).

It could also be a setup problem, but I'dont know yet.

I also want to record with 44100 samples p/s .
During the time I have tried different sample rates, but there's still the same problem.

I hope someone can help me and can give me some advice!

Have a nice day!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm currently experiencing click sounds at the beginning of my audio recordings too.